# Are there infinitely many clones containing all the constant functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

A [**clone**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_(algebra)) on a set $A$ is a collection of $m$-ary functions $A^m \to A$ ($m$ depends on the function) that is closed under composition and includes all projection functions. Clones are significant because for any language of possible operations on $A$, the functions definable from those operations is a clone. Let $n = |A|$.

**Is it true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that there are only finitely many clones on $A$ containing all constant functions?** That is, for each $a \in A$ the clone contains a function $f: A \to A$, such that $f(x) = a$ for all $x$.

#### Motivation

The classic case is where $A = \{0,1\}$; a set of functions is "expressively adequate" if it generates the clone of all functions. It is a famous and fundamental result that sets such as $\{\lor, \lnot\}$ and $\{\to, \bot\}$ are expressively adequate. A more powerful and incredibly beautiful result is [Post's lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_lattice) which completely characterizes ALL countably many possible clones on $\{0,1\}$. Wikipedia states: "the lattice of clones on a three-element (or larger) set [has] the cardinality of the continuum, and a complicated inner structure."

But I have an alternate definition of expressive adequacy in mind where we wish to always allow constants $0$ and $1$. Thus we restrict to those clones containing the constant functions, and we find that there are only *finitely many* clones on $\{0,1\}$. In fact, there are 7 clones:

- $UM$, which contains just constant functions and projections
- $\Lambda$, the set of conjunctive functions
- $V$, the set of disjunctive functions
- $U$, the set of essentially unary functions (depend only one one coordinate)
- $A$, the set of affine functions
- $M$, the set of monotone functions
- $\top$, all functions.

Thus I am interested in whether there are still finitely many such clones for a set of size greater than $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question in your title is yes.

Ágoston, I.; Demetrovics, J.; Hannák, L. On the number of clones containing all constants (a problem of R. McKenzie). Lectures in universal algebra (Szeged, 1983), 21–25, Colloq. Math. Soc. János Bolyai, 43, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1986.

''Answering a question raised by McKenzie, the authors prove that over any finite set with
at least three elements there are continuously many clones containing all constants. Here
a clone over some set
A
is a set of finitary functions over
A
containing all projections
and closed with respect to composition.''

Images of the article from [Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=1MfSBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=%22On+the+number+of+clones+containing+all+constants%22&source=bl&ots=341ZB8ANH_&sig=jebu9zwxKJkFTfE8So-ANnRRmVM&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22On%20the%20number%20of%20clones%20containing%20all%20constants%22&f=false):

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

Comment: Thanks! Seems like it answers it. I'll try to find the article but leave this up for a while in case there is an available proof.

Comment: @6005 The entire article is available [on Google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=1MfSBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=%22On+the+number+of+clones+containing+all+constants%22&source=bl&ots=341ZB8ANH_&sig=jebu9zwxKJkFTfE8So-ANnRRmVM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid2pTB_7vVAhVX6GMKHd1hAa8Q6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22On%20the%20number%20of%20clones%20containing%20all%20constants%22&f=false).

Comment: @NoahSchweber and it's short :D